Lemma for Hermite Interpolation
I'm working on a Numerical Analysis project and I'm doing Hermite interpolation using divided differences.
We noticed the repetition of nodes. So, we defined
$$z_{2i}=z_{2i+1}=x_i, \ 0 \leq i \leq n.$$
Thus,
$$f[z_{2i},z_{2i+1}]=f'(x_i), \ 0 \leq i \leq n.$$
We wanted to prove by induction on n that the solution of the Vandermonde system is
$$a_k=f[z_0,\ldots,z_k].$$
However, we are having trouble adapting the following lemma for the repetition of nodes and with $z$ notation:
$$f[x_j,...,x_{j+k}] = \sum_{l=j}^{j+k} \frac{f(x_l)}{\prod_{\substack m=j \\m \neq l}^{j+k} (x_l - x_m)}.$$
